# How can I debug / view the generated query when using's the olivere/elastic elasticsearch go library?

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out what the generated query is for the https://github.com/olivere/elastic library, as in the actual JSON value query that gets sent to the elasticsearch server.

There is some documentation about a trace log (which I've used as shown below) but this does not seem to include query.

```
client, err := elastic.NewClient(
...
elastic.SetTraceLog(log.New(os.Stdout,"",0)),
)
```

I also can't seem to find anything relevant in the docs here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/olivere/elastic?utm_source=godoc

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the library, but a general solution is to insert a logging proxy between your application and the remote service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can provide your own HTTP client:

> // Obtain a client. You can also provide your own HTTP client here.
> client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetErrorLog(errorlog))

Well, that's where the documentation ends :)... and actually you must provide a `Doer` interface.
I instantiated a struct that implements the `Doer` interface and decorated the `http.Do()` in order to log the http.request dump:

**Disclamer:**
This is just a minimal example I used against an elastic instance running in a docker container, for the scope of this question. In production, don't run insecure TLS, don't hard-code credentials, configure the http transport as needed etc.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"

    "github.com/olivere/elastic/v7"
)

type LoggingHttpElasticClient struct {
    c http.Client
}

func (l LoggingHttpElasticClient) Do(r *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    // Log the http request dump
    requestDump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("reqDump: " + string(requestDump))
    return l.c.Do(r)
}

func main() {
    doer := LoggingHttpElasticClient{
        c: http.Client{
            // Load a trusted CA here, if running in production
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
            },
        },
    }

    client, err := elastic.NewClient(
        // Provide the logging doer here
        elastic.SetHttpClient(doer),

        elastic.SetBasicAuth("elastic", "<password>"),
        elastic.SetURL("https://<address>:9200"),
        elastic.SetSniff(false), // this is specific to my docker elastic runtime
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    /*
        Generate a random HTTP request to check if it's logged
    */
    ac := client.Alias()
    ac.Add("myIndex", "myAlias").Do(context.Background())
}
```

And here is the output:

```
reqDump: POST /_aliases HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9200
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic base64(<user>:<pass>)
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: elastic/7.0.32 (linux-amd64)

{"actions":[{"add":{"alias":"myAlias","index":"myIndex"}}]}
```

I assume the `SetTraceLog` may also be used, but I went for the known path.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would guess this took some effort to complete!

Comment: I’m glad I could help. It was a bit annoing to figure out why it wasn’t working without SetSniff(false) in docker, but the rest was fun to code. Appreciate your comment and upvote!